# How to draw the proof of Pythagoras (Zhaoshuang's Proof) in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I need to draw that fig.(ref to the pic below). I have referred to some practices, but still to no result. I am stuck at the point how to draw a grid? Thx....

[image]

Comment: This post could be a start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586572/

Comment: And, for the grid you can write `\draw (0,0) grid (7,7);` for example.

Comment: How can I roate the rectangle to the pic's location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a possible solution (minus the Chinese characters). I use the Ti*k*Z `calc` library to find the center points of the triangle edges (not really necessary) and I place first all the needed coordinates. The code could be reduced, but I think that this way is more explanatory.

```
\documentclass {standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % for midpoints like ($(A)!0.5!(B)$)

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% coordinates
\coordinate (A) at (7,4);
\coordinate (B) at (3,7);
\coordinate (C) at (3,4);
\coordinate (D) at (7,7);
\coordinate (E) at (0,3);
\coordinate (F) at (4,0);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (8,8); % for centering wrt the grid (probably not necessary)
% drawing
\fill[pink!50]    (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle; % big square background
\draw[gray]       (O) grid (D);                      % grid
\draw[thick]      (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle; % big square
\draw[blue,thick] (B) |- (A); % line from B to A, first vertical then horizontal
\draw[blue,thick] (E) -| (F); % line from E to F, first horizontal then vertical
\draw[blue,thick,fill=yellow] (3,3) rectangle (4,4); % little square
% points and labels
\foreach\i in {A,B,C} % points and red dots
  \fill[red] (\i)  circle (2pt) node [above right] {$\i$};
\node[red] at (D)             [above right] {$D$}; % dotless point
\node[red] at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) [right]       {$a$}; % midpoint between B and C
\node[red] at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$) [above]       {$b$}; % midpoint between A and C
\node[red] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) [above right] {$c$}; % midpoint between A and B
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Copy of your image

First of all I'll make a copy of the image you want to draw

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Colors define
\definecolor{myRed}{HTML}{A43A44}
\definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{F9EAE3}
\definecolor{myYellow}{HTML}{ECCB46}

% Important positions
\node (A) at (7,4) {};
\node (B) at (3,7) {};
\node (C) at (3,4) {};
\node (D) at (7,7) {};

% Big rectangle color
\fill[myOrange,opacity=0.7] (4,0) -- (0,3) -- (B.center) -- (A.center) -- cycle;

% Here we draw the grid and te colored square
\fill[myYellow] (3,3) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[] (0,0) grid (7,7);

% Big rectangle
\draw[very thick] (4,0) -- (0,3) -- (B.center) -- (A.center) node[midway,myRed]{\textbf{c}} -- cycle;

% Position labels
\node at (A.east) [xshift=5] {\textbf{A}};
\node at (B.north) [yshift=5] {\textbf{B}};
\node at (C.west) [xshift=-5] {\textbf{C}};
\node at (D.north east) [xshift=1,yshift=1] {\textbf{D}};

% Thicker lines of the box
\draw[thick] (C.center) -- (A.center) node[midway,myRed]{\textbf{b}};
\draw[thick] (3,3) -- (B.center) node[midway,myRed]{\textbf{a}};
\draw[thick] (4,3) -- (0,3);
\draw[thick] (4,4) -- (4,0);

% Circles
\foreach \n in {A,B,C}
    \fill[myRed] (\n.center) circle[radius=0.07];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: img]

but I will make a little explanation of my code.

## Explanation

The first I did was make the colors that you have in your image, that way it is as close as possible to yours.

```
\definecolor{myRed}{HTML}{A43A44}
```

Then I defined the important positions that appear in te image.

```
\node (A) at (7,4) {};
```

the code above creates a node with name `A` in the position `(7,4)` and with no label `{}` (the empty braces are needed).

After that I make the colored part of the square because I think it looks like to be behind the grid

```
\fill[myOrange,opacity=0.7] (4,0) -- (0,3) -- (B.center) -- (A.center) -- cycle;
```

as you can see I make a combination of normal coordinates `(x,y)` and node coordinates `(name.position)`.

I made then the yellow square and the grid

```
\fill[myYellow] (3,3) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[] (0,0) grid (7,7);
```

(the order is necessary to avoid the color to get over parts of the line)

In the next part I made the border of the big square

```
\draw[very thick] (4,0) -- (0,3) -- (B.center) -- (A.center) node[midway,myRed]{\textbf{c}} -- cycle;
```

as you can see I added after the vertex in `A` the code `node[midway,myRed]{\textbf{c}}` this tells tikz to put a node with label `\textbf{c}` in the middle of the way from the previous two in our case `A` and `B`.

I added the node labeling then

```
\node at (A.east) [xshift=5] {\textbf{A}};
```

I label the points with the same node name syntax for the coordinate and added a little shift because it looks better that way.

And at the end I add a little loop

```
\foreach \n in {A,B,C}
    \fill[myRed] (\n.center) circle[radius=0.07];
```

It take each node and make a circle in it.

###### P.D.

I made a [document](https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=https://amadocab.github.io/Intentopages/main.tex) with the code and my own version if you are interested, and sorry but I don't know how to add the other characters

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without `calc`, inserting labels through `pos` options while drawing `paths`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mylabel/.style={red, opacity=1},
    dot/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt, fill=red, draw=none, opacity=1}]
    
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\draw[thick, fill=red!20, fill opacity=.5] (0,3) -- (3,7) node[dot, label={[mylabel, above right]$B$}] {} -- node[midway, mylabel, above right]{$c$} (7,4) node[dot, label={[above right, mylabel]$A$}]{}--(4,0)--cycle;
\draw[blue, fill=yellow] (3,3) rectangle (4,4);
\draw[blue, thick] (0,3)-|(4,0) (3,7)|-node[pos=0.25, red, right] {$a$} node[pos=0.5, dot, label={[mylabel, above right]$C$}]{} node[pos=0.75, red, above]{$b$} (7,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is simplest one!

Answer (score 1):

The labels are not necessary, in my opinion. Also see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610575/140722).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[join=round,
tri345/.pic={\draw[thick,red,fill=pink!50] (0,0)--(4,0)--(0,3)--cycle;}]

\fill[yellow] (0,0) rectangle (1,-1);

\path 
(0,0)   pic{tri345}
+(1,-1) pic[scale=-1]{tri345}
+(0,-1) pic[rotate=90]{tri345}
+(1,0)  pic[rotate=-90]{tri345};

\draw[gray] (-3,-4) grid (4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```